# Call Swift function with parameters from Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a library class wrote in swift which should be used in my existing objective-c code.
I have created the bridging-header and have define @class MySwiftClass in .h and import "-Swift.h" in .m

a swift class is something similar to this

```
@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName: String

    public init(firstName: String, lastName: String) throws {
        guard !firstName.isEmpty && !lastName.isEmpty else { throw SOME_ERROR }
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        super.init()
    }


func methodWithParams(city: String, suburb: String) throws -> String {
        return city + suburb
    }
```

I have faced two problems.

1. Don't know how to call swift `init` function on the objective-c class. I have tried `MySwiftClass *myClass = [MySwiftClass init];`. Up to this, the app can compile. But don't know how to pass the parameters.
2. I also want to access `myClass.methodWithParams(city:"My city", suburb:"My country")` in objective-c class.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: The first thing you need is to add `@objc` to the methods which should be visible from Objective-C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You must call alloc before init call.

   ```
   MySwiftClass* instance = [[MySwiftClass alloc] initWithFirstName: @"John" lastName: @"Doe"];
   ```
2. Mark method with `@objc` or use `@objcMembers` to make your method exposable from Objective-C code. And unfortunately you can't user throwable initializers in Objective-C.

   ```
   @objcMembers class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
       var firstName : String
       var lastName: String

       public init(firstName: String, lastName: String) throws {
           guard !firstName.isEmpty && !lastName.isEmpty else { throw SOME_ERROR }
           self.firstName = firstName
           self.lastName = lastName
           super.init()
       }

       func methodWithParams(city: String, suburb: String) throws -> String {
           return city + suburb
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You _can_ use throwable initialisers from Objective-C - the signature just has an extra `NSError ** error` parameter

Comment: @lgzar Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate an object in Objective-C…

```
NSError *error = NULL;
MySwiftClass *class = [[MySwiftClass alloc] initWithFirstName: @"John"
                                                     lastName: @"Smith" 
                                                        error: &error]
```

to call the method

```
[class methodWithParamsWithCity: @"My CIty" suburb: @"My suburb" error: &error];
```

`throws` in Swift appends an `NSError ** error` parameter in Objective-C

Comment: Here it would be `[[MySwiftClass alloc] initWithFirstName:@"first" lastName:@"last" error:&error]` since the init method throws as well.

Comment: This is me digging back into my 4 years old Objective-C memory - I knew that, but thought I was going crazy when testing it out it wasn't compiling. I thought maybe something had changed in the Obj-c world that had passed me by. It was the missing @objc

Comment: I have accepted lgzar's answer only because of @objcMembers.Sice I cannot accept two answers, I have given +1 to your's since both help me to resolve the problem. Thanks a lot